# Access to iterated controls in repeated sections in Orbeon

Tags: xpath, orbeon

When setting repeated content in a section in Orbeon each control is repeated and the their names are the same. How do I access the the control from the first, second...etc instance of a control from each iterated section? I'm thinking along the lines of $control-name[instance#] or something similair.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following works, given [this form](https://gist.github.com/orbeon/e7272c1b2499c3a5fb5f):

- `$name[2]`: return the second value
- `string-join($name, ', ')`: join all values with commas
- `count($name)`: return the number of values

See also [the relevant documentation](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/wiki/XForms-~-Model-bind-variables).

Comment: Thank you very much ebruchez. That's exactly what I had in mind.

Answer (score 0):

To access this value in "bind" section, you can use a relative path , like ../name=''.

TO access this value in "body" section, then you can use context()/../name.

If you are trying to make anything different, be more specific and this answer can be edited to be according to what you want.